# I am trying to raise an error if 1 value is 1 or second value is 3, but I am getting some error? Any thoughts?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

how to create a trigger just to prevent either to insert another if either 1 value is 1 or second one reached 3? if first is 1, 3 can still be inserted to second one, and if second one is 3, 1 still can be inserted into the first?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_check_sum 
   BEFORE INSERT OF ON visitor
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   Maxnon               NUMBER;
   Maxpri               NUMBER;
   Maxlim               NUMBER;
   vl_out_of_range      EXCEPTION;

BEGIN


  SELECT permvisid, primaryvisqty, othervisqty, vislimit INTO Maxnon, Maxpri, Maxlim
  FROM visqty
  WHERE permvisid = :NEW.visresid;


    IF (Maxpri = 1  OR Maxlim = 3) THEN
    RAISE vl_out_of_range;
  END IF;
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN vl_out_of_range THEN
     Raise_application_error (
      -20300,
      'Visitor '|| 'limit' ||' out of range for '
     );
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20322, 'Invalid Job Classification');
END;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You have a stray `OF` in the declaration... that would give "ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type"?

Comment: `BEFORE INSERT OF ON` and trying to `SELECT` 4 columns `INTO` 3 variables.

Comment: Selecting 4 values into 3 variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_check_sum 
  BEFORE INSERT ON visitor
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  Maxnon          NUMBER;
  Maxpri          NUMBER;
  Maxlim          NUMBER;
  vl_out_of_range EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT primaryvisqty,
         othervisqty,
         vislimit
  INTO   Maxnon,
         Maxpri,
         Maxlim
  FROM   visqty
  WHERE  permvisid = :NEW.visresid;

    IF (Maxpri = 1  OR Maxlim = 3) THEN
      RAISE vl_out_of_range;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN vl_out_of_range THEN
    Raise_application_error(
      -20300,
      'Visitor limit out of range for '
     );
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20322, 'Invalid Job Classification');
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d653380d3040e7161299104865b73f15)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day! Can I ask you last question? How to let this be ignored if no previous data found? I'm trying to insert all 48 rows?

WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20322, 'Invalid Job Classification');
END; 

can instead of raise app, could continue?

Comment: @ArtursRadionovs `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;`